# resx file to json with specific format in c#

Tags: c#, json

I want to covert resx file in the below json format can you please help me with the same.

```
{
"TagText.p1":"Inspiration, Motivation",
"TagText.p2":"och utbildning för",
"TagText.p3":"ABO",
"TagText.p4":"globalt...",
"TagText.p5":"Var som helst / När som helst"
}
```

I have tried the below code.
var xml = File.ReadAllText(@"\Default.aspx.sv-SE.resx");
var obj = new Object();

```
        obj = new
        {
            Texts = XElement.Parse(xml)
                .Elements("data")
                .Select(el => new
                {
                    Key = el.Attribute("name").Value,
                    Value = el.Element("value").Value.Trim(),
                })
                .ToList()
        };
        
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: Can you post some of the source xml? what are the contents of `obj` before you try to serialize it?

Comment: @Jonathan please find the below code
     <data name="About.h1" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Om</value>
    <comment>ABOUT</comment>
  </data>
  <data name="AboutUs" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Om oss</value>
    <comment>ABOUT US</comment>
  </data>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For best results, I think you want to put into a dictionary, and then serialize *that*. And I'm assuming that your xml has some parent tags wrapping the whole lot of it:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var theXml = @"<myXml><data name=""About.h1"" xml:space=""preserve""> <value>Om</value> <comment>ABOUT</comment> </data> <data name=""AboutUs"" xml:space=""preserve""> <value>Om oss</value> <comment>ABOUT US</comment> </data></myXml>";

        var obj = XElement.Parse(theXml)
            .Elements("data")
            .Select(el => new
                {
                    Key = el.Attribute("name").Value,
                    Value = el.Element("value").Value.Trim(),
                })
            .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
        
        Console.Write(json);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "About.h1": "Om",
  "AboutUs": "Om oss"
}
```

see:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/fQuZZj